# How do I solve 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column_name'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to map a column in my dataframe from [Yes, No] to [1,0] without having to create multiple variable dummy columns.
I did using:

`df['A'] = df.A.map({'Yes':1, 'No': 0})`

where df is the dataframe and A is a column in the dataframe. It worked, However I have several columns I'll like to map, so I created a function.

```
def mapping(df, column_name):
 mapped =  df.column_name.map({'Yes':1, 'No':1})
 df = df.replace(column_name, mapped)
 return df
```

There was no objection in the jupyter notebook, it ran. but when I called the function and inserted my values like

```
mapping(df, B)
```

I get the following error:

```
'AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column_name''
```

How do i solve this please?

Comment: Instead do: `df[column_name].map({'Yes':1, 'No':1})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement that is causing the error is ;

```
mapped =  df.column_name.map({'Yes':1, 'No':1})
```

In pandas, this line tries to access the column named 'column_name'. That means, this does not take the string stored in the variable 'column_name' but instead takes 'column_name' as a string and tries to find the attribute called 'column_name'.

Instead, you can use the statement;

```
mapped =  df[column_name].map({'Yes':1, 'No':1})
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I also restructured the function:                                                       
 def mapping(daf, column_name):
 daf[column_name] =  daf[column_name].map({'Yes':1, 'No':0})
  return df

Comment: Kudos, that function is much more efficient. Glad to help. Can you please also accept my answer?